# Firestore: can't match midnight with date filter in where() clause

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I realized there is a strange behavior when using a `where()` clause on a `Timestamp` field in a Firestore `query()`. I'm using the modular version 9 of Firebase.

Maybe someone has an explanation for that.

So here's the data I see in the Firebase/Firestore console:

[image]

Assuming, that today is the **27th December 2021**, I want to query all documents for this day - in this case, only the one document from above.

I would use the following query (i.e. everything after today at midnight and before tomorrow at midnight):

```js
const today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0));
const tomorrow = new Date(new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate() + 1));
const docQuery = query(collection(getFirestore(firebaseApp), 'ticks1'),
    where('date', '>=', today),
    where('date', '<', tomorrow)
)
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(docQuery)
console.log('documents count:', querySnapshot.docs.length)
```

**But: this returns no results!**

```
documents count: 0
```

Instead, if I change the value in the database to **12:00:01 AM** (see below), it works and I retrieve the expected document.

[image]

```
documents count: 1
```

Can somebody explain this behavior - or is it a bug in the Firestore implementation?

Comment: How do you check the results?

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the hint. I added some debugging infos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Cloud Function query by DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199104/firestore-cloud-function-query-by-date)

Comment: @FaridShumbar thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work as expected either. even if I use the Timestamp object in the query, I don't get any results. `let date = new Date(new Date(now).setHours(0,0,0)); const timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(date);`

`where('date', '==', timestamp)`

Comment: Does your first solution work if you specify mseconds? `const today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));`

Comment: @FaridShumbar for a brief moment I thought it was fixed, but it still doesn't work as expected, even with mseconds precision. I'm not sure if there is some side effect in my code, but it works for me with the interval `(Yesterday 23:59:59, Today 23:59:59]`. 

Comment: Thanks @AlexGru, perhaps you could post the solution you currently use as an answer for better visibility, until we find another option?

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative solution I'm using at the moment

Instead of the range `[today 12:00:00 AM, tomorrow 12:00:00 AM)`
, I'm using this date range now: `(yesterday 11:59:59 PM, today 11:59:59 PM]`

```js
const now = new Date()
const dateFrom = new Date(new Date(new Date(now).setDate(now.getDate() - 1)).setHours(23,59,59))
const dateTo = new Date(new Date(dateFrom).setDate(dateFrom.getDate() + 1));
const docQuery = query(collection(getFirestore(firebaseApp), 'ticks1'),
    where('date', '>', dateFrom),
    where('date', '<=', dateTo)
)
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(docQuery)
console.log('documents count:', querySnapshot.docs.length)
```

```
documents count: 1
```

At least this makes sense, even though it looks a bit odd.