# how to query docs in firestore based on the date you chose in firestore V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

i want to fetch the docs based on  a date im inputing , and these docs have their timestamp in docs data , i tried querying with where() but still not working or maybe im not doing in the right way

im getting the date from this library

```
  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };
 <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
```

And this is my query

```
  const finishedRef = collection(db, "validatedOrders");
     const finishedQ = query(
       finishedRef,
       where("status", "==", "Delivered"),
       where("date", "==")
     );
const finishedSnapshot = await getDocs(finishedQ);
     finishedSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       finished.push(doc.id);
     });
```

Comment: The code you shared defines a query `finishedQ`, but doesn't [read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) from it as far as I can see.

Comment: i updated the post where i used the data , the problem is i want to get the docs with same date as the one i got from the date picker , but didnt know how

Comment: That depends on what values the `date` fields in your database have. If they are `Timestamp` values, you'll need to use add both `>=` and `<` conditions on that field for the range of timestamps for the `date` values you want returns.

Answer (score 1):

If the `date` fields in your database have `Timestamp` values, you'll need to use add both `>=` and `<` conditions on that field for the range of timestamps for the `date` values you want returns.

See for an example of this: [Firestore Cloud Function query by DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199104/firestore-cloud-function-query-by-date) and [Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range)